# Why attr_accessor won't work in setting methods

Tags: ruby, class, oop, getter-setter, object-oriented-analysis

I am implementing BST in ruby and writing insert method using recursion.

I am trying to use attr_accessor for setting and getting root but it doesn't work. Can anyone help out?

```
class Node 
  attr_accessor :value, :left_child, :right_child

  def initialize (value)
    @value = value 
    @left_child = nil 
    @right_child = nil 
  end
end 

class BST 
  attr_accessor :root 

  def initialize
    @root = nil
  end 



  def insert(value, node)

    if node == nil 
      node = Node.new(value)
      return node
    end 

    return node if node.value == value

    if node.value > value
      if node.left_child == nil 
        node.left_child = Node.new(value)
        return
      else 
        insert(value, node.left_child) 
      end 

    else

      if node.right_child == nil 
        node.right_child = Node.new(value)
        return
      else 
        insert(value, node.right_child) 
      end
    end 
  end 
end 


mybst = BST.new
p mybst.root
mybst.insert(1, mybst.root)
mybst.insert(2, mybst.root)
mybst.insert(10, mybst.root)
mybst.insert(12, mybst.root)

p mybst
```

The code above shows a simple implementation of Node class and a BST class with insert method. Gives me `#<BST:0x00557398d02378 @root=nil>`

If I use a self.root it works.

One can use @root to access the root but a class should not interact with its instance variables directly. That's why we need a getter and setter method provided by attr_accessor. But it's not working. What I am missing ?

Below are the screenshots of the book POODR. It says never to use instance variables directly even in class.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Keep in mind the only things in Ruby that are logically false are `nil` and `false` so unless there's some way that things like `right_child` can ever be literally `false` it's not necessary nor recommended to do comparisons like `== nil`. This not only clutters your code up and raises questions about what values that property can contain, but runs the risk of an accidental assignment if you type `= nil` by mistake.

Comment: @tadman Hey! I wanted to give a review if the OP took it over to CR.se! ;)

Comment: @thesecretmaster That's just the beginning. There's a lot you could convey here to make it more Ruby-like.

Comment: @tadman I know, I was just kidding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually *totally* OK to use instance variables within instance methods. In fact, that's what they're for! Setters and getters allow things outside the instance to access variables inside the instance. They (basically) define instance methods for the class like this:

```
class Foo
  # getter -- Same as attr_reader :root
  def root
    @root
  end

  # setter -- Same as attr_writer :root
  def root=(root)
    @root = root
  end

  # attr_accessor defines a setter *and* a getter.
end
```

So, you could simplify your code by defining `#insert` so that it only takes one argument (`value`) and replace every place where you reference `node` with a reference to `@root`.

The way that I think you're looking for (but is not the "right" way, and I wouldn't recommend) is to call the `root` and `root=` methods defined by the accessor.

If you took this route, you'd also have to define `#insert` to only take `value` as an argument and replace every place that you reference `node` with `root`. This will work, but it's not the right way to solve the problem. If you solve it this way, please ask a question on CodeReview.se so I can clarify how you can make the code better.

### Why it's not working

In the #insert method, you're manipulating the `node` parameter that was passed to the method, not `root`. Ruby is pass by value not pass by reference (sorta), so when you pass `mybst.root` to `#insert`, you're effectively passing `nil` because `mybst.root == nil`. Then the `mybst.insert` call returns a new Node, but you don't do anything with that return value. If you wanted to set `root` to that return value, you could do:

```
mybst = BST.new
p mybst.root
mybst.root = mybst.insert(1, mybst.root)
mybst.root = mybst.insert(2, mybst.root)
mybst.root = mybst.insert(10, mybst.root)
mybst.root = mybst.insert(12, mybst.root)

p mybst
```

### Explanation of what that textbook is *trying* to say

I think that the confusing part here is where the textbook says:

> Hide the variables, even from the class that defines them

This is correct, but I think you're misinterpreting it. This section is saying that you should hide instance variables *from anything outside of that instance*. Within that instance, it's totally OK to use them, and that's actually the reason why instance variables exist -- to store state within the instance. It's just considered better to define methods for behaviors rather than directly exposing the instance variables. Of course, this is just one rule to keep in mind -- I'm sure you'll come across a situation where this advice does not apply, but generally you want to keep instance variables internal.

Comment: Once you've got *completely working code*, you can also post on [codereview.se] for a review (I'd be happy to give you one).

Comment: I have added the screenshots of the POODR book by Sandi Metz which says never to use an instance variable in your code.It's not recommended.

Comment: The phrasing is ... not the best. I'll add an explanation to my answer.

Comment: My concern is if getter and setter methods are available, even if I am wrapping, why is it not working and updating the values?

Comment: The getters and setters are there to allow you to access the instance variables from *outside* that instance. As I mentioned in my answer, they effectively define methods that allow direct manipulation of instance variables.

Comment: It's saying hide variables even from the class itself as illustrated on page 25. And yeah that's only a good practice. That's not the main concern. My main concern is why won't it work if I am using the wrapper as getter and setters instead of using instance variable or self. to access them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161948/discussion-between-thesecretmaster-and-saurav-prakash).

Comment: Found out, ruby treats assignment as assignment to a new variable and not the instance variable if we do root = Node.new(5). For that reason we need to pass self.root = Node.new(5).
And from your last explanation, it makes sense that in the start if I pass a nil, it will give me an error. Bcoz root is nil.so assignment will return no value for nil. Afterwards when we pass the root, now its an instance. 
Thanks man!

Comment: posted the working code on CR. Will appreciate your reviews. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/183630/ruby-bst-code-for-insertion-implementation